# Controlling Phone from ubuntu desktop?

Tags: android, remote

Is there any way to see my screen and controll my Android smartphone from my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop computer?

(possibly with little to no latency?)

Comment: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/08/scrcpy-ctrl-shift-keyboard-support and https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/05/kde-connect-android-redesign-rolling-out

Answer (score 1):

As ChanganAuto said above, scrcpy is really nifty for this. To get it:

1. enable ADB on your phone
2. `apt install scrcpy`
3. connect phone via USB (tcp is also possible)
4. `scrcpy`
5. your phone may ask if you want to allow the connection, go ahead with that

Check out the readme on github as well for loads of other options: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy